# I use Core Plot to draw a view but find 'CPTAnnotation.h' not found

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I recently switch to developer version 4.3 and found CPTAnnotation.h not found issue ,which was not there befor. Any idea what i am missing. This is related to coreplot. Thanks

Comment: @iscavengers  have U solve the issue? Thank u

Comment: I do not understand the method you point me ,and I want to have some useful demo about line chart using core plot .And can drag around.

Comment: Did you verify that your header search path is still correct?

Comment: Yes,that is the problem ,I need to add one more search path /Users/apple/Desktop/Kiwi_Project/CorePlot_0.9/Source/framework/iPhoneOnly beyond /Users/apple/Desktop/Kiwi_Project/CorePlot_0.9/Source/framework